# Сложная синтаксическая конструкция

Tags: синтаксис

Пьер улыбнулся, Наташа засмеялась, но Николай ещё более сдвинул брови и стал доказывать Пьеру, что никакого переворота не предвидится и что вся опасность, о которой он говорит, находится только в его воображении.

В этом предложении три смысловые части? И если да, правильно ли они выделены?

{ [   ] }, { [   ] , но [   ] },  {(что) и (что, (о которой),...)} .

Comment: Орфографическая ошибка: не прЕдвидится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если выделять смысловые части, то здесь повествование о действиях трёх человек - Пьера, Наташи и Николая, следовательно, деление таково:

[ ] ,  [ ] , но { [ ], (что) и (что, (о которой),...)} .

Два простых предложения, соединённых бессоюзно, + сложноподчинённое с тремя придаточными, соединёнными однородной и последовательной связью.